# Statistical uncertainty in average of continuous variable, where values are not expected to be the same

Tags: mean, uncertainty, measurement, methodology

I have been trying to understand statistical uncertainties on measurements made, I have found many partial sources, but they seem to either deal with

1. simply counting whether something happened or not
2. dealing with repeated measurements of the same quantity, therefore assuming that any variation is due only to uncertainties or statistical fluctuations.

Neither of the above is my case ... My current requirement is to take the results of some blood tests and find an average for particular blood markers. Let's say cholesterol.

I have a group of 100 people, I measure their cholesterol. I will get 100 different results with continuous values. There will be a distribution due to the fact that people can have different values rather than due only to uncertainty. I would probably assume (not sure if correctly) this would still be normally distributed.

I want to extract the average value and the uncertainty.

**Questions:**

- What would you suggest as the best approach?
- How would I need to modify this approach if I had a million people to test, or if I only had one?

Comment: If data are normal and sample random, use the sample mean $\bar X = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ to estimate the population mean $\mu$ and the sample standard deviation $S = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i (X_i - \bar X)^2}$ to est the pop. SD $\sigma.$ // You can find confidence intervals to assess how good these point estimates are. Look at stat text.  // A random sample of size $n = 100$ should give useful results unless the data have outliers. Precision of estimates gets better as $n$ gets larger. If $n = 1,$ you can't estimate $\sigma$ and the single observation may be relatively far from $\mu.$

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I understand this is the standard deviation. A measure of the spread around the mean. Is this a measure I can quote as the sampling or statistical "uncertainty" in the mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For normal data a 95% confidence interval for the population mean $\mu$ is of the form
$$\bar X \pm t^*S/\sqrt{n},$$ where $t^*$ cuts 2.5% from the upper tail of Student's t dist'n with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

- For $n > 30,$ a good approximation is $t^* \approx 2.$ You can get the exact value from a printed table of t dist'n; look at row $n-1$.
- For $n=100$ it's $t^* = 1.984$ obtained in R by code `qt(.975, 100)`, which returns 1.983972.

The quantity $S/\sqrt{n}$ is called the ***standard error of the mea**n*. The quantity $t^*S/\sqrt{n}$ (half-width of the confidence interval) is called 95% ***margin of error*** for estimating $\mu.$

**Example:**

Suppose cholesterol determinations from 100 men randomly chosen from a particular population are as generated below. (I'm no expert on cholesterol,
so these may not be realistic. However, these fake data are good enough for a demonstration of the statistical ideas.)

Computations from R:

```
set.seed(1234);  x = round(rnorm(100, 130, 12));  x
  [1] 116 133 143 102 135 136 123 123 123 119
 [11] 124 118 121 131 142 129 124 119 120 159
 [21] 132 124 125 136 122 113 137 118 130 119
 [31] 143 124 121 124 110 116 104 114 126 124
 [41] 147 117 120 127 118 118 117 115 124 124
 [51] 108 123 117 118 128 137 150 121 149 116
 [61] 138 161 130 122 130 151 116 146 146 134
 [71] 130 125 126 138 155 128 113 121 133 126
 [81] 128 128 114 128 140 138 137 125 128 116
 [91] 129 133 150 142 124 134 116 141 142 155
```

Their sample mean is $\bar X =128.13$ and their sample standard deviation is
$S = 12.04.$ The standard error is $S/\sqrt{100} = 1.204.$

```
mean(x);  sd(x)
[1] 128.13
[1] 12.04005
```

From these data, the best estimate of $\mu$ is $\bar X = 128.13.$ But that is unlikely to *exactly* correct. In R, the `t.test` procedure gives a 95% confidence interval $(125.741, 130.519)$. The relevant
part of the output is shown below:

```
t.test(x)

...
95 percent confidence interval:
 125.741 130.519
...
```

Notice that these 100 observations have smallest value 102 and largest value 161. However, using the information from all 100 values we can be reasonably sure that the *population
mean* $\mu$ is between 125.741 and 130.519. [Because my fake data were generated using $\mu = 130$ we know that the confidence interval contains the 'true' mean in this particular example. But in a real-life study, you would
not know the true mean.]

```
min(x);  max(x)
[1] 102
[1] 161
```

*Note:* Now you should try to find formulas in your textbook that match
the ones I have shown here. Then follow through any specific examples given there.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, really helpful :)